# How to take Hbase table snapshot?

Tags: export, backup, hbase, restore, snapshot

I am new to Hbase and I was looking for Hbase backup and restore solution. CAn you please mention how to take snapshot of Hbase or Hbase table and restoring it as part of recovery solution?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Login to hbase shell 
 
snapshot 'table_name','snapshot_name' 
 
you can see whether it create a snapshot or not 
from hbase shell, type list_snapshots

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to do this in HBase directly (though there is work going on for this even as we speak: see [HBASE-6055](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6055). That's targeted for 0.96, meaning late 2012 or early 2013.

In the mean time, if you use another underlying file system besides HDFS, some of them (like the closed-source commercial product, MapR) offer a snapshot feature (for a price).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a snapshot of a table is as simple as running this command from the HBase shell:

```
hbase(main)>  snapshot 'myTable', 'MySnapShot'
```

Restoring is as simple as issuing these commands from the shell:

```
hbase(main)>  disable 'myTable'
hbase(main)>  restore_snapshot 'MySnapShot'
hbase(main)>  enable 'myTable'
```